# Is my method of approximation correct to solve this question?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, functions, derivatives

*(I hope this one to be an appropriate question over StackExchange platform.)*

Given $y = \dfrac{\sqrt{1 + 2x} \sqrt[4]{1 + 4x}}{\sqrt[3]{1 + 3x} \sqrt[5]{1 + 5x} \sqrt[7]{1 + 7x}}$, to find $y'(0)$. $$y = (1 + 2x)^{\frac{1}{2}}(1 + 4x)^{\frac{1}{4}}(1 + 3x)^{-\frac{1}{3}}(1 + 5x)^{-\frac{1}{5}}(1 + 7x)^{-\frac{1}{7}}$$

Before differentiating $y$, $lim_{x \to 0} y$ is obtained using the method of binomial expansion and the powers of $x$ greater than $1$ have been neglected. Reason to neglect: as  $x$ tends to $0$, the denominator of $x$ is on the increasing side, hence raising $x$ to higher power (say $a$) lowers its value significantly so that the expression ($x^a$) tends more towards $\texttt{zero}$.

Having said that, $$\lim_{x \to 0} y = (1 + x + ...x^2 + ...)(1 + x + 0)(1 - x + ...x^2 + ...)(1 - x + 0)(1 - x + 0) = (1 + x)^2(1 - x)^3$$

Writing more casually: $$\lim_{x \to 0} y = (1 + 2x + ...)(1 - 3x + 0) \approxeq 1 + (2 - 3)x + 0 = 1 - x$$

So now on differentiating $y$ at $x = 0$, it is expected to get: $y'(0) = 0 - 1$, i.e., $y'(0) = \mathbf{- 1}$.

I duly acknowledge that this method is not an ideal method but I want to enquire whether this type of inference will yield correct answers in most cases or not and whether (all) the inferences used/mentioned here are appropriate. Also tell me how do you feel about this method of solving. Thank you!

Comment: a good trick is you can use is logarithmic differentiation (if it is something you already learned ofc).

Comment: Dear @Colver, thank you for your suggestion. The method of use of $\text{logarithmic differentiation}$ simplified the method of solving to great extent without any use of approximation.

Comment: Dear @Colver, I did not stumble upon this method of solving at the first place. However, this also suggests that my method of approximation is quite correct as the Taylor series expansion of $\log_e (x)$ would result in the expression of the similar fashion as mentioned in the original post. Nevertheless, this method of solving simplifies the process.

Comment: If your goal is just to find $y'(0)$ and not $y'(x) $ then you may directly use the definition $y'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{y(x)-y(0)}{x}$ combined with limit formula $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x}=n$.

Comment: Yes @ParamanandSingh, that method of course directly computes the desired result. Might be considered a better way according to the context of the question though being much similar.

Answer (score 2):

The key facts here:

- $(1+ax)^b=1+abx+o(x)$
- $\prod_i (1+a_i b_i x+o(x))=1+x\sum_i a_i b_i + o(x)$.

Doing that, and treating the denominator terms as multiplication with negative exponents, gets you to $y=1-x+o(x)$ so that $y'(0)=-1$.

Comment: Yes. That's what I've expressed, presuming that it would work in most cases, if not all. And $o(x)$ here may be neglected due to large denominators in its monomial terms.

Comment: @NikhilKumar Right, so what you did is correct, this is just a clearer exposition that ensures that the errors don't somehow propagate to cause a problem.

Comment: Thanks for that!